# Error al tratar de publicar una aplicacion de windows Form c# .NET FRAMEWORK 4.7.2

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Buenos días colegas espero se encuentren bien.

Resulta que tengo una aplicación WINDOWS FORM c# y utilizó el asistente para publicación de visual studio 2019 para generar el ejecutable, todo me funcionaba perfecto pero desde que realice el cambio de nombre del ensamblado me ha estado generando unos inconvenientes, resulta que al cambiarle este nombre, realizo la instalación de la aplicación y ya esta no me aparece en programas y características la aplicación ni con el nombre nuevo ni con el viejo, entonces no puedo realizar desinstalación y en el administrador de tareas la busco y sale con el nombre de Microsoft.NET clickOnce Launch Utility, no sale con el nombre asignado del ensamblado, por favor alguien podría indicarme cómo podría corregir esto ? adjunto imágenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]